# Sort indicator on an asp DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, sorting, datagrid

I have a simple data grid...

```
<asp:DataGrid AllowPaging="true" AllowCustomPaging="true" runat="server" ID="grid"
        PageSize="20" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" 
        OnSortCommand="OnTableSort"
        OnPageIndexChanged="grid_PageIndexChanged" 
   <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="FullName" HeaderText="Name" sortexpression="FullName" />
        ...
```

On sort I'd like to change the Css class of the header column so that I can add an sort indicator using css.  Does anyone know how I could do this in the code behind?  I've Googled for an hour and not found anyone doing this.

```
protected void OnTableSort(object sender, DataGridSortCommandEventArgs e)
{
...
```

By the way I want to use DataGrid.  I don't have time to change to a different control. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You really mean DataGrid and not GridView? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163933.aspx#S1

Comment: Found the answer here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/sorted_datagrid.aspx

Comment: Not sure I would in the future, but it's working ok so reluctant to change it.